# SQL Selecting without parameters?

Tags: vb.net

Im trying to select all records from a database table. Each record has a date in it i want to select all records where that date matches todays date

i created a variable called todaydate and used it within the query but i get No value provided for one or more required parameters error. What possible parameters would i use

Here is the code
Any help would be appreciated

```
    Dim todaydate As Date = Date.Today()
    If DbConnect() Then
        Dim SQLCmd As New OleDbCommand
        With SQLCmd
            .Connection = cn
            .CommandText = "Select * from Tbl_Rental Where DateOfHire = todaydate"

            'parameters????
```

Comment: Depending on what database you're using the syntax varies, but there is always a "today's date" function or system variable available. For example, in oracle you would use "sysdate". Otherwise, you need to add that date as a parameter or concatenate it (don't concatenate it though), there are no other options. Post what database you're using and you may get a more specific solution to querying the current date

Comment: I'm not sure why there are answers suggesting you add a date parameter or use string concat, neither are necessary to query records that match today's date. For oracle, the query would simply be `Select * from Tbl_Rental Where DateOfHire = trunc(sysdate)`, or for sql server `Select * from Tbl_Rental Where DateOfHire = convert(date, getdate())`.

Answer (score 8):

You're not using the variable. However, you should always use sql-parameters not concatenate strings(one reason: avoiding SQL-Injection). I'd also suggest to use the `Using`-statement for the connection and everything else that implements `IDisposable`:

```
Using cn As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
    cn.Open()
    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select * from Tbl_Rental Where DateOfHire = @DateOfHire", cn)
        dim hireDateParameter As new OleDbParameter("@DateOfHire", OleDbType.Date)
        hireDateParameter.Value = Date.Today
        cmd.Parameters.Add(hireDateParameter)
        ' ... '
    End Using
End Using
```

If it's always `Date.Today` you could do that also without a parameter because every database has date functions which return the current date. But since you haven't told us which DB you are using it's hard to show an example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually use your variable, not include it as part of the string.  Try this:

```
.CommandText = "Select * from Tbl_Rental Where DateOfHire = '" & todaydate.ToString("dd/MM/yy") & "'"
```

Comment: I get a data mistmatch error? Is  that because in the database the data type for DateOfHire is a date/time and todaydate is a string?

Comment: Use the `ToString` method of `todaydate`.  See my edit of the answer.

Comment: Nah that doesnt seem to work either. If im changing todaydate to a string that wouldnt work right because DateOfHire is a date?

Comment: Actually, you should use the `ToShortDateString' and then it should work fine at least on SQL Server.

Comment: Actually i think ive found the issue, when debugging Todaydate = 10/25/18 wheras in my database it is 25/10/18 so one is american. Is there anyway to account for this in the code?

Comment: You can convert the format of your date as you need.  See my last edit of the answer.  I can't test this, but it seems like it should work.

Comment: This is why you should use parameters instead. There *are* ways of unambiguously passing a date as a string, but I'm not sure if they're SQL dialect specific (I work with MS SQL). Use a parameter as suggested by Tim Schmelter's answer. It avoids mucking about with conversions and will stand you in good stead when writing other queries with different data types. That said, for this specific problem, I'd probably learn what my SQL dialect's date function is, and not bother passing parameters at all

Comment: I also agree with @Tim, Kevin and soohoonigan that there are better ways to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0):

From a slightly different angle, would it suffice that the date was simply "greater than yesterday"?

```
.CommandText = "Select * from Tbl_Rental Where DateOfHire >= cast(getdate() as date)"
```

This strips the time off the date and anything at or later than midnight today is included.